# Can't get this function to remove specific elements based on subsequent arguments in javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a initial array (the first argument in the destroyer function), followed by one or more arguments. I basically want to use the subsequent arguments as to what to eventually splice out of my array.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var temp = [], j = 0;
  for(var i= 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
     temp.push(arguments[i]);
   }

  while(j < arr.length){

    if(temp[j] === arr[j]){

      arr.splice(j, 1);

    }
     j++;
  }


  return arr;
}
```

**Update**
I forgot to include how it would be executed, if my description was vague.

```
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3) //should return [1, 1]
```

I just get back my original array?!

Comment: Not certain what expected result is? If `arguments` other than `arguments[0]` is in `arguments[0]` array, remove those items from `arguments[0]` array?

Comment: if I call destroyer([5,7,8], 8) should it return [5,7] ?

Comment: need more info on the inputs and outputs...

Comment: Hey Jordan, I added some more information.

Comment: This would work: `function destroyer ( arr ) { return arr.filter( x => [].indexOf.call( arguments, x ) < 0 ) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a **Freecodecamp** challenge? It seems familiar to me.

Here is my approach to solve it.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var temp = [], j = 0;
  for(var i= 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
     temp.push(arguments[i]);
   }
  var resAr=[];
  while(j < arr.length){
    if(temp.indexOf(arr[j])===-1){
      resAr.push(arr[j])
    }
    j++;
  }
  return resAr;
}
console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Comment: It is! WOW, so it I was pretty close. I guess that's relative. Funny not sure why I was down-voted. But I guess that happens.  But I am going to certainly look up `indexOf()` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work but its big-O(n^2) as it need to search element which would be deleted

```
function destroyer(arr) {
    var temp = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    for (var i=1;i<temp.length;i++) {
        for (var j=0;j<arr.length;j++) {
            if (temp[i] === arr[j]) {
                arr.splice(j, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3))
```

Comment: What is "big-O(n^2)", I know I can google it, but figured it would be nice—as an additional piece of documentation to go along with the question.

Comment: It means n^2 runtime (2 nested loops).

Comment: This would work perfect on small array, but I meant if your array has 1,000,000 element and you want to remove those 1,000,000 this would take long time,
if your second arguments are consecutive as it look like in the array then you could find the first element by array.splice(array.indexOf(temp[0]), temp.length)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simpler approach that does not mutate your original array. Also has the benefit of being O(n) since using a hash.

```
function notDestroyer(arr) {
  var lookup = {};
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    lookup[arguments[i]] = true;
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (!lookup[arr[j]]) {
      result.push(arr[j]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```